# Simplest example application to test rails' devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

What is the simplest application that I can download so that I test devise and play around with it? I tried devise_example (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise_example) but it is not compatible with the latest rails' and devise's version. Any other example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sample app I believe is current with Rails 3.2

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-devise-rspec-cucumber

Answer (score 0):

If you havent looked already, [railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com) are great way to get started as well.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

and here is a pro link(need to subscribe)
http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised

Answer (score 0):

The **[RailsApps](http://railsapps.github.io/)** project has up-to-date example applications for Rails 4.1 on GitHub:

> **[Rails 4.1 and Devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/)**
>
> **[Rails 4.1 and Devise and Pundit](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-pundit/)**